# Strings and text, and anger

Tags: c#, string, file-io

I am trying to find a certain string in a text file, then create a folder based off of what that string says, somewhere along the lines, what I have just stops, it doesn't exception, it doesn't spit out errors, it just stops.

the strings I am trying to find are set up like this:

```
50.1 : Oxygas ------> = 1
50.2 : laser -------> = 0 
etc. 

foreach (string file in files)
        {
            string thepathoflife = Path.GetFullPath(file);
            //CreatetheFolder(file)
            string filetocopy = file;
            object bob = file.Clone();
            string bobby = bob.ToString();
            string location = file;
            bool b = false;
            string extension = Path.GetExtension(file);
            string thenameofdoom = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file);
            string filename = Path.GetFileName(file);
            ////bobby.Move(@"\\TEST12CVG\Public\Posts\Temporaryjunk" + filename);
            // string oldlocation = filename+extension;

            if (extension == ".pst" ||
              extension == ".tec" ||
              extension == ".pas" ||
              extension == ".snc" ||
              extension == ".cst" ||
              extension == ".xml")
            {
                b = true;
            }

            if (thenameofdoom == "Plasma" ||
              thenameofdoom == "Oxygas" ||
              thenameofdoom == "plasma" ||
              thenameofdoom == "oxygas" ||
              thenameofdoom == "Oxyfuel" ||
              thenameofdoom == "oxyfuel")
            {
                b = false;
            }


            if (b == true)
            // System.IO.File.WriteAllText(newlocation, bobby);
            {
                bool plasma = false;
                bool oxygas = false;
                bool punch = false;
                bool laser = false;
                var findLevel = 6;
                var path = @thepathoflife;
                var levels = path.Split(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar);
                var second = levels.Length > findLevel ? levels[findLevel] : null; 



     //this is where the problem starts.
 StreamReader s = new StreamReader(@thepathoflife);

                StreamReader st = new StreamReader(@thepathoflife);
                string currentLine;
                string searchString = "50.2 :";
                bool foundText = false;
                string searchStringab = "= 1";
                bool foundTextab = false;

                do
                {
                    currentLine = st.ReadLine();
                    if (currentLine != null)
                    {
                        foundText = currentLine.Contains(searchString);
                        foundTextab = currentLine.Contains(searchStringab);
                    }
                }
                while (currentLine != null && !foundText || currentLine != null && !foundTextab);

                if (foundText||foundTextab)
                {
                    plasma = true; //do something
                }
```

Comment: What is the streamreader "s" used for? It could be a problem opening two streams on the same file.

Comment: Can't see if you close the StreamReader. Also, it seems that you haven't copied all the code. The foreach isn't closed

Comment: `object bob = file.Clone();` - this will provoke anger sooner or larer.

Comment: there is a lot of stuff in the code, this is just a part of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You opened two StreamReader on same file without closing first one:

```
StreamReader s = new StreamReader(@thepathoflife);
StreamReader st = new StreamReader(@thepathoflife);
```

and finally you didn't dispose any of them, use [`using`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) to prevent such a mistakes:

```
using(StreamReader st = new StreamReader(@thepathoflife))
{
 do stuff;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you can simplify things with:

```
foreach (var currentLine in File.ReadLines(thepathoflife))
{
    foundText = currentLine.Contains(searchString);
    foundTextab = currentLine.Contains(searchStringab);
    if (foundText || foundTextab)
        break;
}
```

Comment: that won't help, I need to distinguish the file extensions and stuff still.

Comment: wait, is that replacing the entire thing, or just a small part?

Comment: @shred1894: That's just replacing the part that reads the file.

Answer (score -1):

surround all your code with a try catch block, then spit out the exception to the console (I am assuming you are using a console project)

```
try{, your code...
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }
```